# How to call a stored procedure in SQL Server with output parameter from Web API

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, output-parameter

I do not know how to upgrade this code to retrieve output parameter from a stored procedure. For example that parameter name is `TransactionPassCorrectly` (it is a return parameter for some calculation in database and its type is int)

```
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> UpdateSuperHeroFromSP(int SuperHeroId, string Place)
{
    return await context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync($"UpdateSuperHero {SuperHeroId},{Place}");
}
```

Comment: EF Core Power Tools can map stored procedures correctly for you

Comment: You need to specify the `OUTPUT` keyword in the `EXEC` statement also. Side note: your code (that you mistakenly edited into my answer) doesn't need a transaction as it's only one `UPDATE` statement. Furthermore, instead of messing around with `CATCH... ROLLBACK` just put `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` at the top, which guarantees a rollback in case of error. And then you don't even need this output parameter anyway: if there was an error it would bubble back all the way to C# as an exception. You might want to check the rowcount though, in case the ID was not found at all.

Comment: Why are you using a stored procedure like in the first place? EF Core exists to hide the database. This code brought the database code right into the controller action

Comment: ErikEJ
 Thanks for your answer. I was an output whitch missed from call from webapi.

Comment: Charlieface
Hi,
i have complex query with several return values from 1-10 depends on the some checks. It is not allways an error sometimes is missing some entry in table, or value is not in good format something like that.
Because of that i do not use xact_abort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are't passing parameters there, you are ***injecting*** them, which is dangerous as it can lead to malicious abuse and/or incorrect results. It also doesn't work at all with output parameters.

Instead you need to pass parameters properly (using `SqlParameter`) or you can use `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` which can handle string interpolation without injecting. You then need to pick up the value off the parameter object.

Note that the parameter in the `EXEC` statement needs the `OUTPUT` keyword afterwards.

You should also not rely on parameter order and instead specify the parameter names explicitly.

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> UpdateSuperHeroFromSP(int SuperHeroId, string Place)
{
    var SuperHeroIdParam = new SqlParameter("@SuperHeroId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = SuperHeroId };
    var PlaceParam = new SqlParameter("@Place", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Value = Place };
    var TransactionPassCorrectlyParam = new SqlParameter("@TransactionPassCorrectly", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

    await context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(@"
EXEC UpdateSuperHero
  @SuperHeroId = @SuperHeroId,
  @Place = @Place,
  @TransactionPassCorrectly = @TransactionPassCorrectly OUTPUT;
",
        new object[] {SuperHeroIdParam, PlaceParam, TransactionPassCorrectlyParam });

    return (int)TransactionPassCorrectly.Value;
}
```

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> UpdateSuperHeroFromSP(int SuperHeroId, string Place)
{
    var TransactionPassCorrectlyParam = new SqlParameter("@TransactionPassCorrectly", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
    await context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(@$"
EXEC UpdateSuperHero
  @SuperHeroId = {SuperHeroId},
  @Place = {Place},
  @TransactionPassCorrectly = {TransactionPassCorrectlyParam} OUTPUT;
");

    return (int)TransactionPassCorrectly.Value;
}
```

If the parameter could be `NULL` then you need `return TransactionPassCorrectly.Value as int;` and you need to declare your function `Task<ActionResult<int?>>`.

Note that the return value of `ExecuteSql` is not the `RETURN` of a procedure (which you shouldn't really use anyway), it's just the number of rows modified if any. For return values you would need `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`.

Comment: This solve the issue it missed out param
$" EXEC UpdateSuperHeroOutput {SuperHeroId}, {Place}, {State} out");